# How to set location directive prefix and postfix in nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to use one location directive nginx as a

**/auth/**

Example:-

```
location = /auth/v1/registration
     {
      proxy_pass http://backend1/auth/v1/registration;
     }
```

In this example i want that like if i provide anything before **/auth/** and after **/auth/** is taken by default it only match only **auth**

```
location = *****/auth/*******
     {
      proxy_pass http://backend1/auth/v1/registration;
     }
```

what can i replace with *****
Thankyou in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The regular expressions used by nginx are compatible with those used
>   by the Perl programming language (PCRE).

Try it:

```
location ~* ^.*/auth/.*$ { ... }
```

Tests:

```
# pcretest
PCRE version 8.39 2016-06-14

  re> ~^.*/auth/.*$~i
data> /some/auth/text
 0: /some/auth/text
data> /some/text
No match
data> /auth/text
 0: /auth/text
data> /some/auth/
 0: /some/auth/
data> /some/auth2
No match
```